# How to reference a dynamically assigned dataframe name

Tags: r

I have successfully allocated dataframe names and populated them (see code) but I do not know how to subsequently reference them. So I loop through to assign `df.test1` and populate it with `some data 1` and so on. I know that the `df` has been created, and can view or summary it in the console, but not in the code.

I am pretty new to `R` so am not sure if some of the solutions I have looked at apply to me.

```
num.clusters <- 5
for (i in 1:num.clusters) {
  assign(paste("df.test",i,sep=""), paste("somedata", i))
}
```

This works but Then want to do something like:

```
View(df.test,i)
```

to view whatever iteration from `1` to `5`.

I want to be able to use the assigned dataframes like any other dataframe. I could hard code this as `View(df.test1)` but that would defeat the point. I also want to do other things with the `datframe`, e.g. subsetting.

I know this doesn't work. Would love to know what does.

Many thanks...

Comment: `print(get(paste0("df.test",i))` gives the output of the iteration,  If you just want to follow the step of the iteration, you can put this inside  the loop `cat("df.test",i,"\n")`

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for getting back to me. I don't think I was clear. I will update my question. I want to be able to use df.test1 as a working datadrame, and df.test2 etc.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "working dataframe"? It is accessible already. If  you want to get a dynamic access you can use  `get` function as above. `get(paste0("df.test",i))` returns what you want. I.e , say you assigned a df by `assign(paste("df.test",i,sep=""), as.data.frame(1:10))` then you can subset it via `get(paste0("df.test",i))[3,1]` to reach the 3rd row of 1st column which is 3 for this example.

Comment: You are absolutely right! My bad. Great stuff maydin.

Comment: How do flag the question as answered and give you credit? Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow also...

Comment: Well, since it is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237812/refer-to-a-data-frame-that-was-dynamically-created) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179590/referencing-an-existing-data-frame-with-a-dynamically-created-character-object) question, no need to transform it to an answer. But you may upvote the command if you wish:)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic data frame creation in R with custom names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778608/dynamic-data-frame-creation-in-r-with-custom-names)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the proof that the approach is problematic: avoid using `assign` in general because it makes accessing the variables afterwards awkward (among other issues).

A cleaner way is to just put your "data frames" (copying from your example) in a list:

```
num.clusters <- 5
df.test <- list()
for (i in 1:num.clusters) {
  df.test[[i]] <- paste("somedata", i)
}
```

Then you would just access them like this:

```
View(df.test[[i]])
```

If what you put in there was an actual `data.frame` (and not the strings you were using), you could then access its columns like any other `data.frame`:

```
df.test[[i]]$Name
```

Or

```
df.test[[i]][, "Name"]
```

Comment: And I can still access the original dataframe column names? I realise my original example doesn't have a typical dataframe structure. But if it had columns like 'Name', 'DoB', 'Gender' etc.